# Mount Vista Public Folder in Fedora

Tags: windows-vista, fedora, server-message-block

cant for the life of me remember how to access a public folder on vista  from fedora

using SMB on Fedora.  It seems to connect to the Vista box but not the location...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brain rememberd the firewall - Fedora comes locked down - had to enable SAMBA in the firewall.

EDIT

Apprently its doesnt come locked down - as you can have the option of configing the Firewall during install - or not (locked).  I choose locked when I didnt mine then forgot I had done that, hence thinking that it was =>

Comment: Fedora doesn't comes locked down. You have the choice tune or completely disable the firewall at install time.